# SSH Dynamic Port Forwarding ('ssh -D') in Python

Tags: python, windows, ssh, tunneling, ssh-tunnel

I'm looking for a way to implement SSH Dynamic Port Forwarding ('ssh -D') under Python. The problem is that it has to work under Windows, i.e., running SSH with popen/pexec/etc. won't work. Any ideas?

cheers,

Bruno Nery.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/)?

Comment: Does Paramiko provides dynamic port forwarding? I didn't find any reference to it.

Comment: Paramiko does not support this. But you should add your use case to the issue on Github requesting this feature: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/955

Answer (score 1):

There are ssh executables for Windows, so you can uses the subprocess.Popen approach. This is not exactly elegant, a pure Python approach would be better.

Comment: I don't like the idea of being dependent on another executable. Anyhow, if there is a DLL that does dynamic port forwarding, then we're talking :)